# Is this really on-topic?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

This audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4937522

Is listed as a "Do not close". However, it seems to match exactly the definition of "looking for an off-site library" (maybe not explicitly, but I'm not sure how you would answer without one).

Not only that, but there are no answers, and the comment with 4 upvotes does nothing but *recommend a library*.

Why is this considered on topic?

Also, I would downvote, but it is clear and shows research. How do we remove this from the audits (assuming it is a bad audit)?

Comment: Apparently these audits are getting really hard, since I'm now review banned :( A lot of them seem really questionable...

Comment: there are 2, now 3, VTCs on it

Comment: @Plutonix ["human factor" at work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: I lifted your ban.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Thanks. It seems the question has now been closed. It would be ironic if this were now an audit with a "Close" correct response.

Comment: I don't think it will show up as an audit anymore, now that it's closed.

Comment: @Robert It could be a "must close" audit if it gets enough downvotes.

Comment: @bjb568: With five upvotes, this seems very unlikely.